# How do I resize a button?

Tags: java

How do you resize the button? I've tried various methods like setSize and setPreferredSize but they aren't workng.

```
package tests;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
public class RPS extends JPanel{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Rock Paper Scissors");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JLabel label = new JLabel("<html>Will you choose <i>rock,</i> <i>paper,</i> or <i>scissors?</i></html>");
        JButton button = new JButton("I am a button.");
        label.setHorizontalAlignment(0);
        label.setVerticalAlignment(1);
        frame.pack();
        frame.getContentPane();
        frame.setTitle("Rock Paper Scissors");
        frame.setSize(640, 480);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.add(label);
        frame.add(button);
        button.setToolTipText("Y U no click me?");;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is generally no need to resize a button. The button will determine its own size based on the text and `Font` used by the button. The layout manager will then use this information to give the components a size and location based on the rules of the layout manager.

If you want extra space around the text then you can use:

```
button.setMargin(...);
```

You have many other problems with your code:

```
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.add(label);
    frame.add(button);
```

This won't do anything. By default the content pane of the frame uses a `BorderLayout`. If you don't specify a constraint, then then component is add to the `CENTER`, but only one component can be displayed in the `CENTER` so you only see the last one.

```
frame.setSize(640, 480);
```

There is no need for that statement. The pack() will set all the components at their preferred sizes.

```
frame.setVisible(true);
```

This should be the last statement executed, "after" all components have been added to the frame.

```
frame.getContentPane();
```

This does nothing, you don't assign the returned value to any variable.

```
    label.setHorizontalAlignment(0);
    label.setVerticalAlignment(1);
```

Don't use magic numbers. Nobody knows what 0 and 1 are used for. Read the API for those methods for variables that you can use.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information and working examples to get you started. Start with the section on `How to Use BorderLayout` to understand why your current code isn't working and to understand how to specify the "constraints" when you add your components to the frame.

Comment: The button is taking up the whole page, it isn't determining it's own size.

Comment: @DerekSturm, As I said you are adding the button to the Center of the BorderLayout. The BorderLayout will resize the component to take up all the available space of the frame. Get rid of the setSize() statement and the pack() will do its job. If you don't like the layout then use a different layout manager. I gave you a link to the tutorial, so read the tutorial and download the examples and play with them. Then use an appropriate layout manager for your desired layout.

Comment: Is it possible to have the button not take up the whole frame but still be a good size?

Comment: @DerekSturm, your definition of "good size" is different from my definition. I let each component determine its own size. So all you need to do is use the appropriate layout manager. There are no shortcuts to learning Swing. Read the tutorial and download the examples. Virtually every line of code in your program is wrong. Start with a working example and then make changes.

Comment: I wanted to have some space around the button and not make everything cramped.

Comment: @DerekSturm, Then you should be using borders. Read the section from the tutorial on [How to Use Borders](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html). The tutorial has all the Swing basics. Or you can use a different layout manager, like the BoxLayout which allows you to add extra space between components. Each layout manager is different so you need to read the tutorial. We can't guess all your requirements!

Answer (score -1):

```
package tests;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
public class RPS extends JPanel{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Rock Paper Scissors");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JLabel label = new JLabel("<html>Will you choose <i>rock,</i> <i>paper,</i> or <i>scissors?</i></html>");
        JButton button = new JButton("I am a button.");
        label.setHorizontalAlignment(0);
        label.setVerticalAlignment(1);
        panel.add(button);       <-add button to panel
        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);    <--- you need to say where you are adding the panel onto the frame.
        frame.add(label,BorderLayout.NORTH);    <--- same with the label
        frame.pack();
        frame.setTitle("Rock Paper Scissors");
        frame.setSize(640, 480);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        button.setToolTipText("Y U no click me?");;
    }
}
```

If you want a bigger button in the center, you can modify with this:

```
button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
panel.add(button);
frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);  <--adds to center rather than south
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm pretty new to Java.

Comment: No problem.  Accept my answer :p

Comment: (1-), Don't use setPreferredSize().

Comment: Why not?  The link you provided talks about using them.

Comment: There are better ways to influence the size of the component then hardcoding some random value. See the first suggestion in my answer. This is a more platform neutral approach and allows the sizing to be dynamic in case the LAF, Font, text or any other property of the component changes. Yes, in a simple situation like this it will work, but you are learning bad habits for when you start to design truly dynamic applications.

Comment: Camickr, you must learn how to crawl before you can walk.  I think you guys with 200k points forget what it's like to be a beginner :p